# opcion RegExp para no ingresar caractereres especiales

Tags: javascript, regex

Quiero crear una función la cual no permita actualizar un registro si tiene caracteres especiales.

Esta es la forma como la estoy realizando. Utilizo un RexExp y le ingreso los caracteres:

```
onItemUpdating: function(args)
{   
      var grupo_promocion;
      var c_barra;
      var pattern =  new RegExp(/^[^!@"#$%&\/()]*$/);

      c_barra=args.item.c_barra;
      grupo_promocion=args.item.grupo_promocion;

    if (args.item.grupo_promocion === null || args.item.grupo_promocion == "" ) {
        grupo_promocion="";
    }   

    if(pattern.test(document.getElementById("grupo_promocion"))){
          alert("No se permite ingresar caracteres como @ # & %")
          args.cancel = true;
    }else{
           updategpromocion(c_barra,args.item.grupo_promocion); 
          alert("Se actualizo el grupo de promoción correctamente")
    }

}
```

luego pongo la condición utilizando la función test, pero si ingreso letras y números también me genera la alerta y no me realiza la actualización.

**¿Me hace falta alguna otra condición?**

Comment: Norbey, si la respuesta ha solucionado tu problema, recuerda marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primero, `document.getElementById("grupo_promocion")` refiere al elemento, no al texto contenido. Para obtener el texto, dependiendo de qué tipo de elemento sea, se debe referenciar a [.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), [.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) o [.value](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input) (si es un input).

```
texto = document.getElementById("grupo_promocion").innerText;
```

En cuanto al regex, estás utilizando una [clase de caracteres negada](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-character-set) (nótese el `^` al principio de los corchetes que la niega). El siguiente regex

```
/^[^!@"#$%&\/()]*$/
```

coincide únicamente con textos que no tienen esos caracteres, de principio a fin. Es decir, estás validando al revés de lo que deberías hacer.

---

Si esos son **los únicos** caracteres prohibidos, una opción más sencilla es intentar coincidir con uno solo de éstos para que sea inválido, sin negar la [clase de caracteres](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-character-set):

```
pattern = /[!@"#$%&\/()]/;

if (pattern.test(texto)) {
    // texto inválido
}
```

Ahora bien, ¿estás seguro que se quiere permitir *cualquier* caracter excepto estos? ¡Hay muchos caracteres que probablemente no estés considerando!

En estos casos, suele ser más práctico buscar qué caracteres se permiten, y buscar si existe un caracter que no esté dentro de ese listado permitido:

```
pattern = /[^A-Za-z0-9 ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚüÜ\-]/;

if (pattern.test(texto)) {
    // texto inválido
}
```

Nótese que en este caso sí estamos usando una [clase de caracteres negada](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-character-set). Es decir, coincide con cualquier caracter que no sea `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, espacio, `ñ`, `Ñ`, letras con tilde o diéresis, o guión.

O, si se prefiere, usando el modificador `i` para que no distinga entre mayúsculas y minúsculas:

```
pattern = /[^-a-z\d ñáéíóúü]/i;
```

---

> Nota: como bien dice [PaulVargas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/634/paul-vargas), el rango `A-Z` no incluye letras con
>   tilde, que normalmente uno quiere considerar en textos en español, y
>   la única forma es agregándolos uno por uno en la clase.
>
> [image: Letras con tilde]

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/D6kFliv.jpg

Comment: @Paul jaja, quería dejarlo a elección del autor, pero es cierto que quizás convenga anticiparme.